# How to change label text of a label in a popover view controller when pressing a button in the main view?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm relatively new to Swift. I have a main view controller, `ViewControllerMain`, and a popover view controller, `PopUpVC`, which only has a label. I have a function, `infoClicked` that displays the popover with another function (`showPopover`) when the info button is clicked. When I click the button, I want to change the label text of the popover. However, with the current code, the label always displays "Default".

Here is my code:

```
class ViewControllerMain: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, GetTimesUsed {

     let tipController: PopUpVC = PopUpVC().self

     @IBAction func infoClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
          tipController.tipText = "Success"
          showPopover()
     }

     func showPopover() {

        let myViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupController")

        myViewController?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 200)
        myViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

        let popOver = myViewController?.popoverPresentationController
                popOver?.delegate = self
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.GifView.alpha = 0.7
        })

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.45) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.present(myViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
                popOver?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
                popOver?.sourceView = self.view

        var passthroughViews: [AnyObject]?
        passthroughViews = [infoButton]
        myViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = (NSMutableArray(array: passthroughViews!) as! [UIView])

        popOver?.sourceRect = infoButton.frame
    }
}
```

```
class PopUpVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tip: UILabel!
    var tipText: String = "Default"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tip.text = tipText

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you also add the showPopover function code for reference?

Comment: seems you are instantiating popoverController twice. Once in `let tipController: PopUpVC = PopUpVC().self` and again in your show popover method as ` let popOver = myViewController?.popoverPresentationController`

So try and add popOver.tipText = "Success" in your showPopover method

Comment: I did as you said with `myViewController` in `showPopover`, but it says that `Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'tipText'`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Misread the code. Just to be clear does your popupController with class` PopUpVC` have a storyboard identifier set as `"popupController`"? if so then please check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you seem to be instantiating the popup controller 2 times, so try it like this in your showPopOver code:

```
 let myViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:   "popupController") as! PopUpVC

    myViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 200)
    myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    myViewController.tipText = '' //set to what ever
```